# View Quoted Retweets Tweetinvi

Tags: tweetinvi

knowing the id of a certain tweet, I want to get all Quoted Retweets of that tweet.
There is actually a method that gets all Retweets (tweet.GetRetweets()) but quote retweet is not considered a retweet...

Is there a way to get all Quoted Retweets of a single tweet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately quoted retweets are considered as simple Tweets that include a Hyperlink media to the original tweet.

The Twitter API does not provide an endpoint to perform such request, therefore the only way to access them would be to use the Search API which is currently limited to 7 days.